# Python integrals

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve the integral of `(2**(1/2)*y**(1/2)/2)**2` from `0` to `5` (also shown [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%282%2a%2a%281%2F2%29%2ay%2a%2a%281%2F2%29%2F2%29%2a%2a2+from+0+to+5)). I've been using

```
func = lambda y: (  2**(1/2) * y**(1/2)/2  )**2 and a == 0 and b == 5
from scipy import integrate
integrate.quad(func, a b)
```

For some reason, I keep getting the value 1.25, while wolfram says it should be 6.25? I can't seem to put my finger on the error.

p.s. sorry for the error katrie, i forgot that python uses and not && for logical AND

---

**SOLVED:**
this was a silly int/float error. thank you everyone.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? In many versions of Python, `1/2` will evaluate to `0`. Also, your WolframAlpha link shows the answer for the integral of `y/2` between 0 and 5.

Comment: Also, you do know that the function you've written above is just `y/2`, right? You're squaring a square root...

Comment: the quad function takes the bounds as arguments, however, your worry about the values as integers may be the key. katrie, yes I do, that's a coincidence in this example. thanks though.

Comment: Python uses `and` for logical and, `&` is bitwise. But why is that in the function you're trying to integrate, anyway? I can't reproduce your bug, btw... `integrate` works just fine for me.

Comment: Oh, apologies, did I break your code when I reformatted it? If so oops =) sorry.

Comment: heh. you're right again, i just wrote that off the cuff to give background to my question, i should have been more careful.  Actually at this point I've confirmed that the problem is that they are integers not floats. The equation was generated by `sympy.Eq(func, var)`, so i'm gonna have to figure out a way to force that to all floats or something i'm not really sure, but that's not really in the scope of this question. thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let me write your function in *normal* mathematical notation (I can't think in Python). I don't like `**`, as it gets confusing:

```
(2**(1/2)*y**(1/2)/2)**2      =>
(2^(1/2) * (1/2) * y^(1/2))^2 =>
2 * (1/4) * y                 =>
y / 2
```

So to integrate, antidifferentiate (I'm just thinking aloud):

```
antidifferentiate(y / 2) = y^2 / 4
```

Therefore

```
integral('y / 2', 0, 5) =
5^2 / 4 - 0^2 / 4 =
25 / 4 = 
6.25
```

Right. Have you tried replacing `1/2` with `0.5`? It could be interpreted as the quotient of two integers, which is rounded up.

Try this (as the others have suggested):

```
func = lambda y: (2**(0.5) * y**(0.5) / 2.0)**2.0 & a == 0 & b == 5

from scipy import integrate
integrate.quad(func, a b) # What's 'a b'? Maybe 'a, b' would work?
```

Good luck!

Comment: The problem was just the integers. thanks for taking the time to write all that! I have to ask, are you involved with Blender somehow?

Comment: I am quite involved (as a user, not as a developer). I'm still resurrecting BlenderOS, as that failed years ago.

Comment: Also, no problem. Honors Calculus finals are this week, so I integrate in my sleep ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Python sees `(1/2)` and evaluates it with integer division, yielding zero.

Answer (score 0):

Well what's the value supposed to be? Also, you should put more parenthesis in your equation. I have no idea what `(2**(1/2)*y**(1/2)/2)**2` gets parsed out to be.

Comment: sorry, thats why I linked to wolframalpha, it should be 6.25. p.s. added some spacing to OP

Comment: That may be how wolfram is parsing it, but is that how python is parsing it?

Comment: yes, python actually solved for x from y = 2*x**2, and it checked out with wolfram

Comment: Why have you posted this as an answer?